# Linq Where clause with two conditions, not working

Tags: linq

I have three tables:

```
[Products]
    Id
    Title
    Info
    Price

[ProductCategories]
    Id
    Title
    ParentId

[ProductsInCategories]
    Id
    ProductId
    ProductCategoryId
```

I'm trying to read a selection of products in a certain category. The code I have doesn't concider the ProductCategoryId, and just loads all products from the Product table. Where's my mistake?:

The id-variable is a method argument. The value coming in is correct.

```
var ProdInCat = from p in _context.Products
                from pc in _context.ProductsInCategories
                    .Where(x => p.Id == x.ProductId && x.ProductCategoryId == id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Title,
                    p.Info,
                    p.Price
                };
```

Comment: You're not using `pc` *at all* in your query after introducing it. That looks like a mistake to me. It also looks like this should be a join or group join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join products with a filtered list of products in categories based on your external (computed) `id`.

```
from p in _context.Products
join pc in _context.ProductsInCategories.Where(pic => pic.ProductCategoryId == id).DefaultIfEmpty() 
on p.Id equals pc.ProductId
```

More about how can you achieve this at the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Answer (score 1):

Use Inner join expression

```
var ProdInCat = from p in _context.Products
                from pc in _context.ProductsInCategories.Where(x => x.ProductCategoryId == id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                on p.Id equals pc.ProductID
                select new {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Title,
                    p.Info,
                    p.Price
                };
```